# How do I get the first value of multiple records? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

There are two tables, one is "users" and another one is "screenings"
A user can have multiple records in screenings.
I need to get the date of the earliest records from one's multiple screening record.
And see if the earliest record of one's screening has been 30 days since now.
How do I do that?

I got a query like this:

```
   SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, clients.name AS client, 
    users.social_security_number AS ssn, users.hiredate,  
    screening.id AS screening_id, screening.date AS screening_date, screening.maileddate AS screening_maileddate
    FROM users  
    INNER JOIN clients
    ON(
       users.client_id = clients.id
       AND users.client_id = '1879'
       )
    LEFT JOIN screening
    ON(
       users.id = screening.user_id
    )
    WHERE 
    (users.hiredate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-08-14'
    OR users.hiredate IS NULL)
    AND users.id IN(        
    SELECT users.id from users
    INNER JOIN screening sall
    ON(
      sall.user_id = users.id 
    )
    INNER JOIN screening s1
    ON(
      s1.user_id = users.id

      AND s1.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
    ) 
    INNER JOIN screening s2
    ON(
      s2.user_id = users.id

      AND s2.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
    ) 
    INNER JOIN screening s3
    ON(
      s3.user_id = users.id

      AND s3.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
    )
    INNER JOIN screening s4 
    ON(
      s4.user_id = users.id

      AND s4.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
    )
    INNER JOIN screening s5
    ON(
      s5.user_id = users.id

      AND s5.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
   )
    INNER JOIN screening s6
    ON(
      s6.user_id = users.id

      AND s6.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
   )
   WHERE (s1.cholesterol IS NOT NULL
   AND s2.ldl IS NOT NULL
   AND s3.triglycerides IS NOT NULL)
   AND (s4.glucose IS NOT NULL 
   OR s5.ha1c IS NOT NULL)
  )

    GROUP BY users.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FIRST(column_name) command to get the value of the first record.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: I tried and it can only be put in the select statement. But if I want to do judgement and see if it has been 30 days, I need to right another sub-query and it is very complex for the query I have. is there any other ways?