# How do I compare the first value of multiple records? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

There are two tables, one is "users" and another one is "screenings" A user can have multiple records in screenings. I need to compare the date of the earliest records from one's multiple screening record, and see if it has been 30 days from now. How do I do that?

I got a query like this. I want the first screen.date of specific user and compare it to make sure if it has been 30 days from now. I put the AND screening.date + INTERVAL 30 DAY > NOW() that way, but it doesn't work the right way. It compares the date of a user's multiple screenings. But I just want the first one.

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, clients.name AS client, 
users.social_security_number AS ssn, users.hiredate,  
screening.id AS screening_id, screening.date AS screening_date, screening.maileddate AS screening_maileddate
FROM users  
INNER JOIN clients
ON(
   users.client_id = clients.id
   AND users.client_id = '1879'
   )
LEFT JOIN screening
ON(
   users.id = screening.user_id
)
WHERE 
(users.hiredate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-08-14'
OR users.hiredate IS NULL)
AND users.id IN(        
SELECT users.id from users
INNER JOIN screening sall
ON(
  sall.user_id = users.id 
)
INNER JOIN screening s1
ON(
  s1.user_id = users.id

  AND s1.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
) 
INNER JOIN screening s2
ON(
  s2.user_id = users.id

  AND s2.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
) 
INNER JOIN screening s3
ON(
  s3.user_id = users.id

  AND s3.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
)
INNER JOIN screening s4 
ON(
  s4.user_id = users.id

  AND s4.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
)
INNER JOIN screening s5
ON(
  s5.user_id = users.id

  AND s5.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
 )
INNER JOIN screening s6
ON(
  s6.user_id = users.id

  AND s6.date BETWEEN '2011-05-15' AND '2011-11-15'
 )
 WHERE (s1.cholesterol IS NOT NULL
 AND s2.ldl IS NOT NULL
 AND s3.triglycerides IS NOT NULL)
 AND (s4.glucose IS NOT NULL 
 OR s5.ha1c IS NOT NULL)
)
AND screening.date + INTERVAL 30 DAY > NOW()
 GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the first value of multiple records? (MySQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353283/how-do-i-get-the-first-value-of-multiple-records-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

It is much more advisable to simply fetch records from your DB and leave the comparisons and/or other computations to your programming logic. It is far more efficient on your resources and is more readable-cum-maintainable than such large queries.

Comment: I agree with what you said. But I am a new programmer, so leaving the whole things to programming logic is not easy for me. That is why I want to get it done in queries

Comment: @user what programming language are you using? Can you post the relevant segments of the `code` here? May be then someone (here) might be able to help you move ahead in a far more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

What check123 said, but specifically, try using this query (or similar), and then using your application to see if the returned result was more than 30 days ago.

```
SELECT users.id AS user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, clients.name AS client,
       users.social_security_number AS ssn, users.hiredate, screening.id AS screening_id,
       screening.date AS screening_date, screening.maileddate AS screening_maileddate
FROM users  
INNER JOIN clients ON( users.client_id = clients.id AND users.client_id = '1879' )
LEFT JOIN screening ON( users.id = screening.user_id )  
ORDER BY screening_date
LIMIT 1
```